# TextView SetText is not refreshing the text on UI Android

Tags: android

I am using `ScheduledExecuterService` which is fetching data through a service call after a time interval. I am trying to update a `TextView` with `.setText()`, which does not happen. The text changes when I reopen the app otherwise it does not update.

The code is:

```
ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();


            Runnable task = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    AsyncTask asynctask = new AsyncTask() {
                        @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                            // tv.setText("abc");
                            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url_PATH3).build();
                            Response response = null;
                            try {
                                response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                    return response.body().string();
                                }  else {
                                    return response;
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                            TextView DT = findViewById(R.id.DateTime);
                            TextView DI = findViewById(R.id.DeviceID);
                            TextView TP = findViewById(R.id.Temperature);
                            String[] AllDevices = o.toString().split(Pattern.quote("},{"));
                            String[] Dev1 = (AllDevices[0].split("\":\"|-|\","));
                            String[] Dev2 = (AllDevices[1].split(","));
                            DI.setText(Dev1[1] + "," + Dev1[2]);
                            TP.setText(Dev1[4]);
                            DT.setText(Dev1[6]);

                            Log.d("test", "msg");

                            Dictionary Device1;


                        }
                    }.execute();

                }
            };
            worker.schedule(task,5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);  

}
```

Hopes for suggestion or guidance

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove the `@SuppressLint("WrongThread")` annotation, in order to face the problem: that you run an `AsyncTask` on another thread, which tries to update the UI thread. Nesting that `AsyncTask` in a `Runnable` also appears strange. The most easy would be to define an `interface` which can be used for a callback, on `onPostExecute()` ...and let an `Activity` or `Fragment` implement that `interface`, which will then update the `TextView` on the UI thread.

Comment: I remove the @SuppressLint("WrongThread") but the issue did not resolve. Can u please elaborate things for defining interface to use as callback